# Get residues of the function inside a closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

For a function

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^{iz}}$$

Calculate the integral using the residue theorem

$$
\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{1-e^{iz}}\cdot  \mathbb{d}z
$$

where $\; \gamma :  |z+\pi|=\frac{3}{2}\pi$

The function has a singularity for $z=0$, but since the complex exponential funcion is periodic of $\;T=2\pi i$, the function has infinite singularities given by $z=0 + 2\pi in$ where $n$ is an arbitrary integer.

However, there is only one singularity inside the closed contour $\gamma$.

- For $n=-1, z=-2\pi i\quad$ outside contour
- For $n=0, z=0\quad$ inside contour
- For $n=1, z=2\pi i\quad$ outside contour

My question is, how can I get the residue of the function for the singularity $z=0$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has  a pole of order $1$ at $0$ and the residue is $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {z-0} {1-e^{iz}}=\frac 1 {-i}=i$ (as seen by L'Hopital's Rule or by power series expansion of $e^{iz}$)

Comment: Thank you very much